# 2D Ising model simulations: Wolff algorithm acceptance probability with an external magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, simulations, ising-model

I have implemented the Wolff algorithm to simulate a 2D ferromagnet. It works by building a cluster of like spins and flipping them all at once to move quickly through phase space. In the case of no external field and in interaction Hamiltonian which depends only on nearest neighbor interactions, the acceptance probability for adding a spin to the cluster is particularly simple. It works like a charm, but I would like to generalize it to include the contributions from an external magnetic field. All the resources I can find only take into account nearest neighbor interactions. If I add an external field to the mix, is there still a nice form for the acceptance probability?

Comment: The answer seems to be in section 2 here: http://latt.if.usp.br/cgi-bin-delyra/cntsnd?technical-pages/twawesab/Text.pdf

Unfortuantely, because at low T the cluster size is typically macroscopic, even a small external field means an overwhelmingly large likelihood of rejection of the cluster flip if it goes against the external field, and the algorithm slow down catastrophically. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If the field is very close to zero, this should be ok. If not, then I don't see the point of using a cluster algorithm, just do spin flips.

Comment: @KBriggs: The Wolff acceptance is a function of $\Delta E$ from flipping a spin, why not just including in this  energy variation the contribution from the coupling to the B field: $\Delta E \rightarrow \Delta E + 2*B*\sigma_{ini}$?

Comment: @Learningisamess The Wolff acceptance without external field is just 1 (you always accept the move).